# Why couldn't Scrimgeour arrange his own meeting with Harry?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Half-Blood Prince* first Cornelius Fudge and then Rufus Scrimgeour pressure Dumbledore to sanction a meeting with Harry, hoping to cash in on Harry's new-found popularity and credibility in the public eye. Dumbledore refuses to sanction the meeting, to the chagrin of both Ministers.

But, if Scrimgeour was so keen to meet Harry, why couldn't he come and see him in person at Privet Drive. The Ministry knows where Harry lives during the summer; they'd previously sent several owls to his address over disciplinary matters, after all. Dumbledore wouldn't have been able to know about or stop any such meeting.

Scrimgeour ends up taking the opportunity to speak to Harry at the Burrow when he's away from Hogwarts anyway. Surely he had no need to argue with Dumbledore. He could've just gone directly to Harry himself.

**Why didn't Scrimgeour just do the straight-forward thing and visit Harry at Privet Drive?**

Comment: Didn't Dumbledore, Minerva, et al place any number of protections on and around 4 Privet? It really wouldn't be any different than going to Sirius' house or even Hogwarts itself uninvited.

Comment: If I remember rightly what they were trying to achieve, it would have to be an official meeting - a private chat at the Dursley's wouldn't be any good, and they could hardly invite reporters there.  Arranging an official meeting without the Dursley's approval (and good luck with that!) would be legally dicey at best, I guess they felt they couldn't get away with it without Dumbledore's consent.

Comment: (Come to think of it, the fact that Dumbledore could decide unilaterally to leave Harry with the Dursleys suggests that he has *some* sort of authority over Harry, or perhaps orphaned wizard children in general.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston. Well, technically Hagrid kidnapped Harry. No overt permission from the Ministry per se. As for Scrimgeour he wanted to use the initial meeting with Harry to sound him out for future endorsement of the Ministry. The photocall would come later. He suggested that Harry be seen walking inside the Ministry building, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

Scrimgeour's primary business while at the Burrow was Dumbledore's will.  Note that to discharge the will he had to visit Ron and Hermione as well; going to the Burrow simply allowed him to handle the whole thing in one visit.  Trying to get Harry to support the Ministry was a 'while I'm here anyway ...' kind of action.  Plus Scrimgeour was probably too busy to take time out for a separate visit.  And let's face it - getting public Ministry support from Harry Potter was a nice idea but nowhere near a necessity.

One should also consider the possibility that such a visit simply might not occur to him - after all, the magical community has a strong habit of keeping out of Muggle's affairs; deliberately violating such a habit might not come easily to mind.

NOTE: It should be recalled that Scrimgeour DID contact Harry directly, while at Dumbledore's funeral.  Why should he try again right away?

Comment: In movie land, that's true, but in book land Scrimgeour actually goes to The Burrow specifically to talk with Harry. He even uses Percy as an excuse to go there. This is during the "Summer of '96", before Dumbledore's death, where he first asks Harry to be the face of the ministry.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the time period I'm thinking of. I'm asking about the very start of Half-Blood Prince, before Harry had begun his sixth year at Hogwarts. The Scrimgeour visit to the Burrow you're referring to is from *Deathly Hallows*, a year later.